# Excluding model fields on model modification

Tags: django

Is it possible to exclude specific Model fields only when editing it in the Admin panel?
That means, activating the option of

```
exclude = ('field_name')
```

only on "Add model" page, and disabling it in "Edit model" page.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this (and also not Yuji's comment below), but you could try:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude=('bar_field')

    def change_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.exclude=None
    return super(FooAdmin, self).change_view(*args, **kwargs)
```

[see `change_view` for more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods)

Comment: I've ran into this problem before and this solution isn't thread safe. You might want to override the `get_form` method basically copy the code from the source, but override exclude there.

Comment: @user1137119, Because another thread executing say `add_view` could read the attribute `self.exclude` while it has been changed by `change_view`

Comment: PS: change_view would want to add the exclude, and  add_view would want to remove the exclude if you wanted to implement this considering the thread issues. It will just cause strange problems, sometimes.

Comment: @Yuji - thanks. Just find it hard to understand why two different threads will use the same instance of FooAdmin...